# cannot drop table with cassandra and cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, cqlsh

I'm setting a bigdata environment. I'm trying to use Cassandra database, but I'm ignoring something apparently.
I need to change the 'caching' property of the table 'system_trace.events'  to fix a 'spark-connector' issue. 
It crash when handle a 'caching' 'keyword' value  [KEYS_ONLY|ROWS_ONLY|NONE] as it tries to parse value like a json map. 
The main problem is I cannot modify any table.
In order to isolate the problem, I created a new table named 'events2' and set permission to modify it.
Here the code:

```
vaio@vaio-VPCEH30EL:~$ cqlsh -u admin -p 123456
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.2.1 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 20.1.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> LIST ROLES OF admin ;

 role  | super | login | options
-------+-------+-------+------------------
 admin |  True |  True | \x00\x00\x00\x00

(1 rows)

cqlsh> LIST ALL PERMISSIONS OF admin  ;

 role  | username | resource                      | permission
-------+----------+-------------------------------+------------
 admin |    admin |      <keyspace system_traces> |       DROP
 admin |    admin | <table system_traces.events2> |      ALTER
 admin |    admin | <table system_traces.events2> |       DROP

(3 rows)

cqlsh> DROP TABLE system_traces.events2;
Bad Request: Cannot DROP <table system_traces.events2>
```

here the problem:
**Bad Request: Cannot DROP `<`table system_traces.events2`>`**

I change '/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml' to enable sessions

`authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator`
`authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer`

Can somebody detect what i am omitting?

Answer (score 1):

Do not drop system tables. Instead use a compatible version of the connector with your version of Cassandra.

Comment: system_traces.events2 is a fake table.
Versions are compatible according to the documentation.   
     Connector: 1.5    
     Spark: 1.5     
     Cassandra: 2.1.5+